# node.js (using ts-node) referencing local TypeScript module causing TypeError for constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules, ts-node

I'm building a project ReactJS and TypeScript and want to use a module I will share between my web application and API server.

I've used create-react-app with ts-scripts for my web app. I've made my shared module without using a starter project because it's pretty simple.

My web application references my shared module using NPM's local packages feature, the command `npm install --save <path/to/shared/package>`

When I do `npm run start` for my react app I get the error

`TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_validation_shared__.ValidEmail is not a constructor`

**validation_shared** is my unimaginative module name.

The TypeScript causing the error is

`const valid_email = new ValidEmail("john.doe@example.com");`

Is there anything I can change in my configs or setup to get this working? I would love to use typescript & ts-node, and have shared modules.

**Edit - adding code for ValidEmail and the other function in that file.**

```
export function validate(email_address: string): boolean {
    return email_address.indexOf("@") !== -1;
}

export class ValidEmail {

    public email_address: string;

    constructor(email_address: string) {
        if(validate(email_address)) {
            this.email_address = email_address;
        } else {
            throw new TypeError("Invalid value for email address param, it must contains an @ symbol.");
        }
    }
}
```

After more investigation it looks like whatever webpack/bundling process create-react-app uses is bundling the import definitions with the front-end code but not adding the actual class & function definitions.

I found this out by checking the generated code that is loaded into chrome and looking for actual class name "ValidEmail" which isn't present.

**Edit # 2 - console.log output**
I updated my App.tsx to this

```
import { HeaderBar, IHeaderBarProps } from "./components/headerbar";

import * as vs from "validate-shared";

class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {

    console.log(vs);
```

And the result of console.log(vs) is:
`/static/media/index.9d88054a.ts`

When I look at the contents of the file I see only

```
export * from "./ValidEmail";
export * from "./User";
```

This makes sense because it's the contents of my index.ts file for that module. I can't find the "meat" of the files ValidEmail or User anywhere. It looks like the actual code for those classes isn't included anywhere.

Comment: Can you post your code that defines `ValidEmail`?

Comment: What does the import of `ValidEmail` look like?  If you `import * as validation_shared` from the same module and then `console.log(validation_shared);`, what do you see?

Comment: Added the code and some more about my investigation, it looks like either the TypeScript compiler or webpack isn't actually bundling the class and function in the code that gets loaded into the browser.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I got the result of console log and looked at the generated JS files that are loaded into the browser. I updated the question above with the verbose info. Short answer is it looks like the definitions of what I import are either not getting transpiled to JS or not included.

Comment: I'm not sure what to try next based on the information you've provided.  If you publish a repository that reproduces the problem, I will look.

Comment: I'll try and get a repo up, I need to make sure I'm able to do that. In the meantime thanks for your help and time! I really appreciate it :)